# Финал и не финал Python

Tags: python

Несколько команд участвуют в турнире по игре «Что? Где? Когда?». Согласно регламенту турнира, в финал проходит половина команд (с округлением вверх), набравшие больше правильных ответов, чем остальные. Помогите жюри сформировать итоговый протокол.

Формат ввода
На первой строке указано натуральное число N — количество команд.

Далее следует описание результатов N команд в произвольном порядке. Данные о каждой команде записываются на двух строках: на первой — название команды, на второй — количество правильных ответов. Гарантируется, что количество правильных ответов у всех команд разное.

Формат вывода
Нужно вывести на отдельных строках сначала в алфавитном порядке названия всех команд, вышедших в финал (т. е. команд из лучшей по количеству ответов половины), а затем названия всех остальных команд (также на отдельных строках в алфавитном порядке).

```
s = [[input(), int(input())] for i in range(int(input()))]
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i, len(s)):
        if s[i][1] < s[j][1]:
            s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
s1 = list(s)
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i, len(s)):
        if s1[i][0] < s1[j][0]:
            s1[i], s1[j] = s1[j], s1[i]

for i in s1:
    if i in s[:round(len(s) / 2)]:
        print(i[0])
for i in s[round(len(s) / 2):]:
    print(i[0])
```

Должно вывести:

Магистры
Яндекс.Лицеисты
Обожаемые знатоки
Уважаемые знатоки

Выводит:

Яндекс.Лицеисты
Магистры
Уважаемые знатоки
Обожаемые знатоки

В чём проблема?

Comment: Как вы себе представляете наш поиск ошибки в вашем скрипте, если мы не знаем что и как вы там  навводили?  Может быть оно как раз все выводит правильно, просто вы ей даете неправильные данные на вход?

Comment: Извините, не заметил
Ввод:
4

Уважаемые знатоки
22
Обожаемые знатоки

20

Магистры

24

Яндекс.Лицеисты

23

Answer (score 2):

```
s=sorted(s,key=lambda i: i[1],reverse = True)
s[:int(len(s)/2)] = sorted(s[:int(len(s)/2)], key=lambda i: i[0])
s[int(len(s)/2):] = sorted(s[int(len(s)/2):], key=lambda i: i[0])
for st in s:
    print (st)
```

Результат на ваших данных:

```
['Магистры', 24]
['Яндекс.Лицеисты', 23]
['Обожаемые знатоки', 20]
['Уважаемые знатоки', 22]
```

Привести к нужному вам формату вывода надеюсь сможете сами.

Answer (score 1):

для сортировки есть встроенная функция `sort()`, если использовать эту функцию в решении допустимо, то можно попробовать сделать так:

```
n = 5  # количество команд
s = [['Уважаемые знатоки', 22], 
     ['Обожаемые знатоки', 20], 
     ['Магистры', 24], 
     ['Яндекс.Лицеисты', 23], 
     ['Google.team', 19]]

w = -(-n//2)  # количество финалистов (округление в большую сторону)
s.sort(key=lambda x: -x[1])
print(*[t for t,_ in s[:w]+sorted(s[w:])], sep='\n')
```

результат:

```
Магистры
Яндекс.Лицеисты
Уважаемые знатоки
Google.team
Обожаемые знатоки
```